# I need help understanding java code

Tags: java

I am looking over a friend's code and I'm in a java 2 class.  What is the difference between system.out.format and system.out.println?  Also, can I get a quick description/website that can explain what %-26,25s or %-10,10s, etc does in this project?  Finally, with j.getxxx, what does the j. do in this project?  Or, is there a site explaining it better? Thanks for any help

```
for(int i=0; i<inventory.size(); i++){
                Product j = inventory.get(i);
                System.out.format("%-26.25s",j.getName());
                System.out.format("%-10.10s", j.getInventoryCode());
                System.out.format("%-6s", j.getType());
                int avgRating = j.getAvgUserRating();
                String stars = "";
                int k = 0;
                while (k<avgRating){
                    stars= stars +"*";
                    k++;
                }
                System.out.format("%-7s", stars);
                System.out.format("%6d", j.getUserRatingCount());
                System.out.format("%7d", j.getQuantity());
                System.out.format("%7.2f", j.getPrice());
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Comment: There is a good explanation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Comment: Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Please do *not* deface your question in this manner. People have put effort into posting answers, and it's not fair to them.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` simply prints out the string with no formatting. `System.out.format` allows for additional formatting before output, such a padding or decimal precision.
[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)

The `%-6s` is him formatting the output with padding.

`j.` indicates that the method that follows is a member of the object `j`

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println writes to the stdout(console) and the System.out.format returns a String object.

Which to use depends on the sole purpose. If you want to display the string in the stdout (console), then use the first. If you want to get a handle to the formatted string to use further in the code, then use the second.

```
Product j = inventory.get(i);
```

here j is reference variable of Product class. At the time of creating the object you are assigning the reference of that object to reference variable so that later you can call the class method with the help of reference variable. As in your code you are using this for calling getName() method like

```
j.getName();
```